# How to Import the External url images to the magento Using CSV

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am new to magento, I have around 6000 Products have to import them through CSV.. but the images are in the URL format.. how to import them to magento... I am using magento Version 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Consider the path is exm/one/image.jpg
then u need to create a folder exm in your media folder in that exm create one folder and finally in that one folder place your image.
Then continue importing.
Hope it will work

Comment: i am using the external URL for the Image Like http://www.domainame.com/images/pic.jpg

Comment: check this http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-import-product-images-from-external-url-in-magento/